# Running PowerShell with different user

Tags: automation, windows-server-2008, powershell-4.0

Can anyone help me with run command to open PowerShell as different user?

Currently I am trying to run below command

```
Runas /noprofile /user:domain\username powershell
```

It works but I have to provide password once powershell window opens, is there any way where I can directly put password in run command?

Or even if I get to know how can I run any commands from PowerShell using different user without opening new ps window. e.g need to run below command using different user.

```
Restart-Server -Name testservice
```

Comment: The canonical way is to create a scheduled task to run as a different user and store the credentials with the task.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I am trying to open powershell as Admin or different user,  can you suggest how can i have the script created that can have the credentials?

Comment: Write a script like normal. Create a scheduled task to run that script as a different user. Store the credentials of that user with that task. Invoke the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `schtasks.exe`. You can get the help using `schtasks.exe /?`

If you are getting any errors after using this command referring the examples, update the post with the error, we are here to help you.

Update:
There is an in-built cmdlet available in PowerShell `Register-ScheduledTask`, but its depended on OS and is available only from Windows Server 2012 onwards.

Comment: Oops, only noticed PS Version, just updated the post.